# Bad Request 400 при отправке get запроса с параметром. В postman все работает а в проекте ошибка

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, axios, postman

Стек: react, nextJS, TS

Это мой запрос

```
const axios = require('axios');
let data = JSON.stringify({
  "username": ""
});

let config = {
  method: 'get',
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/profiles/?size=10&page=0',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJoYXdlY2loODk3QHJpZHRlYW0uY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg5Nzg3MDIzLCJleHAiOjE2ODk4NzM0MjN9.75OnueL1sV-oaY-nBUYbSFoPR9XEP00tF_i9nSNPFm0'
  },
  data : data
};

axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

data это параметр который я отправляю

ошибка:

```
{
  "stack": "AxiosError@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:24:19\nsettle@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:24:12\nonloadend@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:117:66\nEventHandlerNonNull*dispatchXhrRequest@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:131:7\n__webpack_exports__.default<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:63:10\ndispatchRequest@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:61:10\nrequest@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:157:77\nwrap@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/bind.js:9:15\nInnerSearch@webpack-internal:///./src/components/inner/InnerSearch.tsx:40:51\nrenderWithHooks@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16305:27\nupdateFunctionComponent@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19583:20\nbeginWork@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21596:16\nbeginWork$1@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27421:14\nperformUnitOfWork@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26552:12\nworkLoopSync@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26461:22\nrenderRootSync@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26429:7\nperformSyncWorkOnRoot@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26080:34\nflushSyncCallbacks@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12042:22\nflushSync@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26196:7\nscheduleRefresh@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27790:14\nperformReactRefresh/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-refresh/cjs/react-refresh-runtime.development.js:265:17\nperformReactRefresh@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-refresh/cjs/react-refresh-runtime.development.js:254:26\napplyUpdate@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-refresh-utils/dist/internal/helpers.js:123:31\nstatusHandler@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-refresh-utils/dist/internal/helpers.js:140:13\nsetStatus@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1689793437986:453:55\ninternalApply/<@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1689793437986:624:21\npromise callback*internalApply@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1689793437986:607:64\nhotApply@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1689793437986:555:20\ntryApplyUpdates/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/hot-dev-client.js:269:27\npromise callback*tryApplyUpdates@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/hot-dev-client.js:260:45\nhandleSuccess@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/hot-dev-client.js:53:24\nprocessMessage@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/hot-dev-client.js:181:24\nconnect/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/hot-dev-client.js:16:27\nhandleMessage/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/websocket.js:39:19\nhandleMessage@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/websocket.js:38:28\nEventHandlerNonNull*init@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/websocket.js:64:9\nconnectHMR@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/websocket.js:66:5\n@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/next-dev.js:40:21\npromise callback*@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/next-dev.js:38:4\n./node_modules/next/dist/client/next-dev.js@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1689793437986:236:1\noptions.factory@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1689793437986:661:31\n__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1689793437986:37:33\n__webpack_exec__@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1689793437986:1127:61\n@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1689793437986:1128:53\nwebpackJsonpCallback@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1689793437986:1209:46\n@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1689793437986:9:61\n",
  "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
  "name": "AxiosError",
  "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
  "config": {
    "transitional": {
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "adapter": ["xhr", "http"],
    "transformRequest": [null],
    "transformResponse": [null],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": null,
    "env": {},
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJoYXdlY2loODk3QHJpZHRlYW0uY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg5Nzg3MDIzLCJleHAiOjE2ODk4NzM0MjN9.75OnueL1sV-oaY-nBUYbSFoPR9XEP00tF_i9nSNPFm0"
    },
    "method": "get",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/profiles/?size=10&page=0",
    "data": "{\"username\":\"\"}"
  },
  "request": {},
  "response": {
    "data": {
      "timestamp": "2023-07-19T19:04:49.013+00:00",
      "status": 400,
      "error": "Bad Request",
      "path": "/api/v1/profiles/"
    },
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "Bad Request",
    "headers": {
      "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "expires": "0",
      "pragma": "no-cache"
    },
    "config": {
      "transitional": {
        "silentJSONParsing": true,
        "forcedJSONParsing": true,
        "clarifyTimeoutError": false
      },
      "adapter": ["xhr", "http"],
      "transformRequest": [null],
      "transformResponse": [null],
      "timeout": 0,
      "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
      "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
      "maxContentLength": -1,
      "maxBodyLength": null,
      "env": {},
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJoYXdlY2loODk3QHJpZHRlYW0uY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg5Nzg3MDIzLCJleHAiOjE2ODk4NzM0MjN9.75OnueL1sV-oaY-nBUYbSFoPR9XEP00tF_i9nSNPFm0"
      },
      "method": "get",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/profiles/?size=10&page=0",
      "data": "{\"username\":\"\"}"
    },
    "request": {}
  }
}
```

пробовал по [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501171/400-bad-request-on-a-get-request-which-parameter-its-a-url) ответу обворачивать url в encodeURIComponent, но не помогло

Comment: а обработчик можете показать? код обработчика

Comment: @Gelloiss что вы имеете ввиду под обработчиком? Я делаю запрос сразу в компоненте при загрузке страницы.

Comment: ну а запрос же кто-то обрабатывает? сервер который должен данные отдать, который должен дать ответ при обращении по http://localhost:8080/api/v1/profiles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Браузеры не поддерживают get запросы с параметром.
https://qna.habr.com/answer?answer_id=1829237